# Using watchPosition with arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I'm using the following code to get a users location using [watchPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition). I would also like to define code for the fail parameter and pass options to `watchPosition`, but I'm not sure where the code should go.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
      //Success callback defined, but where shouls fail & options go?
      var positionTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
      var crd = position.coords;

      console.log("Updated user loc...");
      console.log(crd.latitude + " : " + crd.longitude);


      this.myLatitude = crd.latitude;
      this.myLongitude = crd.longitude;

      this.updateUserLocation();
    },
    console.warn("Error getting user location"),
    this.options);
}
else {
  alert("Geolocation not supported in your browser!");
}
```

Comment: It's in the docs you posted. The first parameter is the success callback, the second one the error callback and the third parameter an object with the options. It includes an example

Comment: I know, but I don't know where the callbacks go when using arrow functions.

Comment: `watchPosition((success) => {...}, (error) => {...}, options);`

Comment: @Gerardo is right (Y) that's a very simple arrow function usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you want:

```
const positionTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
  (position) => {
    // Your success code here
    console.log(position);
  },
  (err) => {
    // Your error code here
    console.log(err);
  },
  {
    // Options here
  }
)
```

Just remember:

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

Source: [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

You can use them just like you would use a normal `function` the things that change are just the mentioned above.

You could also declare your arrow functions:

```
const success = (position) => { /* Success code here */ }
const error = (err) => { /* Error code here */ }
const options = { /* Options... */ }

const positionTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```js
const options = {};
const id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((pos) => {
    console.log(pos);
}, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
}, options)
```